# How to test PDF files and variables from import statement using React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

How to test name and pdf file download using React testing library and jest ?

```
import React from "react";
import { name } from "file.json";
import PDF from "./react.pdf";

const Test = () = (
  <>
     <div>{name}</div> //need to test name using RTL
     <Link to={PDF}>React Doc</Link> //need to test PDF file link download using RTL
  </>
);

export default Test;
```